# django admin and restricting staff permissions to just use actions?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

As you know, when give a `can_view` permission to a staff user, that user can view entire fields and able to make changes in any fields if editable.

Is there any feature in Django to make some staff users to restrict to view `change list` but can't get in to record. I just want to make them use only actions in change_list that if I give specific permissions. Otherwise they must just see the list without doing anything.

I know there are options like customizing django admin template or override any admin template. But it takes to much time. I wonder if there is any solution without customize or override.

Comment: You don't have to modify the template. Django permissions by default comes with `add, change and delete` permission. You need to add `view` permission.

Comment: If i did append `view` permission, shouldn't I need to modify list view to forbid the staff user to access editables clicking by link in items list?

Comment: SOLVED: OK, the `change_view` method in the ModelAdmin is the what I am looking for. I'am checked user permission and user type in this method, and I redirect user to error page, if user not fit to requirements.

Comment: You can do that or simply use the mixins if it's a class based view. Have a look at this project: https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces